# Items in a file are being read in a weird order on Xamarin iOS

Tags: file-io, xamarin.ios

I am reading a list of files in a folder in my Xamarin app and displaying them in a ListView. On Android, the files are created and read in the correct order, but on iOS, they are created in the right order, but read and displayed in a weird order and in the exact same weird order every time. I know it's not a problem with the ListView because I was using Syncfusion's SfListView recently and had the same problem with that. Why is it like this?

The correct order of the files:
[image: Android ListView]

What they look like on iOS:
[image: ListView iOS]

My code to create the files:

```
using Partylist.Models;

using System;
using System.IO;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Partylist.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewEventPage : ContentPage
    {
        ...

        // Event handler for when the "Create" button gets clicked.
        async void OnCreateClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Make sure there is something in the text entry.
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EventNameEntry.Text))
            {
                // If there is nothing there, display an error message.
                await DisplayAlert("Oops!", "Your event needs a name!", 
                    "OK");
            }
            // If there is something in the text entry, try to create 
            // a new event with the text as its name.
            else
            {
                // Variable to store the created event.
                Event newEvent = new Event();
                // Variable to store its folder.
                DirectoryInfo newEventFolder;
                // Flag to see if the event was created sccessfully.
                bool eventCreated;
                try
                {
                    // If there's already an event with that name, let the
                    // user know.
                    if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(App.eventFolderPath,
                        EventNameEntry.Text)))
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Oops!", "You already have an event with that name.", "Ok");
                        eventCreated = false;
                    }
                    // Otherwise, try to create the folder.
                    else
                    {
                        newEventFolder = Directory.CreateDirectory(
                            Path.Combine(App.eventFolderPath,
                            EventNameEntry.Text));
                        // Then, create the event based on that folder.
                        newEvent = new Event
                        {
                            EventFolder = newEventFolder,
                            Location = WhereEntry.Text,
                            EventDate = EventDatePicker.Date,
                            StartTime = EventStartTimePicker.Time,
                            EndTime = EventEndTimePicker.Time,
                            Refreshments = RefreshmentsEntry.Text,
                            Activities = ActivitiesEntry.Text,
                            NumGuests = NumGuestsEntry.Text,
                            Theme = ThemeEntry.Text,
                            Budget = BudgetEntry.Text,
                            WillThereBePartyFavors = PartyFavorsEntry.Text,
                            ShouldGuestsBringGifts = GiftsEntry.Text,
                            WillThereBeChildren = ChildrenEntry.Text
                        };
                        // --- Add several premade lists to the event (all of --- //
                        // --- which are empty except the main checklist) --- //

                        // First, the main checklist. Also, set it as such.
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(App
                            .eventFolderPath, EventNameEntry.Text,
                            "Main Checklist.mchec"))) { }

                        // Then, a contact list for important phone numbers.
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(App
                            .eventFolderPath, EventNameEntry.Text,
                            "Important Phone Numbers.cont"))) { }

                        // And another contact list for guests.
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(App
                            .eventFolderPath, EventNameEntry.Text,
                            "Guests.cont"))) { }

                        // The next thing we need is a schedule of activities.
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(App
                            .eventFolderPath, EventNameEntry.Text,
                            "Schedule of Activities.sched"))) { }

                        // After that, a checklist for things to do.
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(App
                            .eventFolderPath, EventNameEntry.Text,
                            "Things to Do.chec"))) { }

                        // And one for things to gather.
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(App
                            .eventFolderPath, EventNameEntry.Text,
                            "Things to Gather.chec"))) { }

                        // And one for things to buy.
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(App
                            .eventFolderPath, EventNameEntry.Text,
                            "Things to Buy.chec"))) { }

                        // And one for things to make.
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(App
                            .eventFolderPath, EventNameEntry.Text,
                            "Things to Make.chec"))) { }

                        // And one that serves as a grocery list.
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(App
                            .eventFolderPath, EventNameEntry.Text,
                            "Groceries.chec"))) { }

                        // There will also be one for things to do the day before the event.
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(App
                            .eventFolderPath, EventNameEntry.Text,
                            "The Day Before.chec"))) { }

                        // And one for things to do the day of.
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(App
                            .eventFolderPath, EventNameEntry.Text,
                            "The Day Of.chec"))) { }
                        // --- End of adding pre-made lists --- //

                        // Let the program know that an event has been created.
                        eventCreated = true;
                    }
                }
                // Should throw an ArgumentException in most cases where there is 
                // an invalid character.
                catch (ArgumentException)
                {
                    // Get all the invalid characters and turn them into a string.
                    char[] invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
                    string invalid = "";
                    foreach(char currentChar in invalidChars)
                    {
                        invalid += currentChar;
                    }
                    // Display an error message.
                    await DisplayAlert("Oops!", "Your event name can't have these characters: \""
                        + invalid + "\".", "Ok");
                    eventCreated = false;
                }
                // If the event was created successfully, start the tip 
                // timer, select the event, open a "List" page 
                // for it, and removed the "New Event" page.
                if (eventCreated)
                {
                    App.tipTimer.Start();
                    App.selectedEvent = newEvent;
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListsPage());
                    Navigation.RemovePage(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my code to read in the files:

```
using Partylist.Models;

using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Partylist.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ListsPage : ContentPage
    {
        // List of lists, used to populate 
        // the page's ListView (see the XAML).
        public ObservableCollection<PartylistList> ListList { get; set; }

        ...

        // Override for OnAppearing().
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            // Regular OnAppearing() method.
            base.OnAppearing();

            // Set the title to be the name of the selected event.
            Title = App.selectedEvent.EventFolder.Name;

            // Set the BindingContext of the page to itself.
            BindingContext = this;

            // Update the ListView.
            UpdateListView();

            ...
        }

        // Function to update the ListView when the page loads or when something changes.
        private void UpdateListView()
        {
            // Set the list of lists to a new ObservableCollection 
            // that we can add stuff to.
            ListList = new ObservableCollection<PartylistList>();

            // Loop to populate the ObservableCollection.
            for (int i = 0; i < Directory.GetFiles(
                Path.Combine(App.eventFolderPath,
                App.selectedEvent.EventFolder.Name))
                .Length; i++)
            {
                // If the current file is the main checklist (filename ends with ".mchec"),
                // then add it to the list of lists as the main checklist.
                if (Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(App.eventFolderPath,
                    App.selectedEvent.EventFolder.Name))[i].EndsWith(".mchec"))
                {
                    ListList.Add(new PartylistList(new FileInfo(Path.GetFullPath(
                    Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(App.eventFolderPath,
                    App.selectedEvent.EventFolder.Name))[i])), new ChecklistPage(),
                    "#FF7700", "master_checklist_icon.png"));
                    // Set a "Rename" button as this thing's only SwipeItem.
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions.Add(new SwipeItem()
                    {
                        Text = "Rename",
                        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ff7700"),
                        CommandParameter = ListList.ElementAt(i)
                    });
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions[0].Invoked += OnRename;
                    // Set this as the event's main checklist.
                    App.selectedEvent.MainChecklist = new FileInfo(Path.GetFullPath(
                        Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(App.eventFolderPath, App
                            .selectedEvent.EventFolder.Name))[i]));
                }
                // If the current file is a contact list (filename ends with ".cont"),
                // then add it to the list of lists as a contact list.
                else if (Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(App.eventFolderPath,
                    App.selectedEvent.EventFolder.Name))[i].EndsWith(".cont"))
                {
                    ListList.Add(new PartylistList(new FileInfo(Path.GetFullPath(
                    Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(App.eventFolderPath,
                    App.selectedEvent.EventFolder.Name))[i])), new ContactsListPage(),
                    "#00DFDF", "contact_list_icon.png"));
                    // Set a "Delete" button as the first SwipeItem.
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions.Add(new SwipeItem()
                    {
                        Text = "Delete",
                        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ff418b"),
                        CommandParameter = ListList.ElementAt(i)
                    });
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions[0].Invoked += OnDelete;
                    // Set a "Rename" button as the second SwipeItem.
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions.Add(new SwipeItem()
                    {
                        Text = "Rename",
                        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ff7700"),
                        CommandParameter = ListList.ElementAt(i)
                    });
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions[1].Invoked += OnRename;
                }
                // Else if it is a schedule (filename ends with ".sched"), then
                // add it to the list of lists as a schedule.
                else if (Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(App.eventFolderPath,
                    App.selectedEvent.EventFolder.Name))[i].EndsWith(".sched"))
                {
                    ListList.Add(new PartylistList(new FileInfo(Path.GetFullPath(
                    Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(App.eventFolderPath,
                    App.selectedEvent.EventFolder.Name))[i])), new SchedulePage(),
                    "#BB0099", "schedule_icon.png"));
                    // Set a "Delete" button as the first SwipeItem.
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions.Add(new SwipeItem()
                    {
                        Text = "Delete",
                        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ff418b"),
                        CommandParameter = ListList.ElementAt(i)
                    });
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions[0].Invoked += OnDelete;
                    // Set a "Rename" button as the second SwipeItem.
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions.Add(new SwipeItem()
                    {
                        Text = "Rename",
                        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ff7700"),
                        CommandParameter = ListList.ElementAt(i)
                    });
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions[1].Invoked += OnRename;
                }
                // Else if it is a checklist (filename ends with ".chec"), then
                // add it to the list of lists as a checklist.
                else if (Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(App.eventFolderPath,
                    App.selectedEvent.EventFolder.Name))[i].EndsWith(".chec"))
                {
                    ListList.Add(new PartylistList(new FileInfo(Path.GetFullPath(
                    Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(App.eventFolderPath,
                    App.selectedEvent.EventFolder.Name))[i])), new ChecklistPage(),
                    "#3F7FFF", "checklist_icon.png"));
                    // Set a "Delete" button as the first SwipeItem.
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions.Add(new SwipeItem()
                    {
                        Text = "Delete",
                        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ff418b"),
                        CommandParameter = ListList.ElementAt(i)
                    });
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions[0].Invoked += OnDelete;
                    // Set a "Rename" button as the second SwipeItem.
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions.Add(new SwipeItem()
                    {
                        Text = "Rename",
                        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ff7700"),
                        CommandParameter = ListList.ElementAt(i)
                    });
                    ListList.ElementAt(i).SwipeOptions[1].Invoked += OnRename;
                }

                // Set the ItemsSource of the ListView in the XAML to the ObservableCollection.
                ListListView.ItemsSource = ListList;
                // Calls OnPropertyChanged() which makes the ListView update.
                OnPropertyChanged("ListList");
            }
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that reads the files?  What is the difference between "weird order" and "correct order"?  Neither of the examples you posted have any obvious ordering to them.

Comment: @Jason I was just adding that when I got your comment. I had to switch computers and couldn’t figure out how to access the question without posting it first. As for the ordering, I wanted to just make the items be read and displayed in the order that I created them, and I ordered them that way because I wanted to group the lists by type.

Comment: you still haven't explained how you expect them to be sorted.  I don't think Directory.GetFiles() promises to return them in any particular order.  You could use GetFileSystemInfos instead and then sort by some specific attribute (creation time, size, etc).

Comment: sorry, I see you specified "order that I created them" in your last comment.  If so then I would use GetFileSystemInfos and sort by creation time.

Comment: @Jason Sorry it took so long to get back to you. I ended up reversing the order that I added the lists and sorting them by last write time using the OrderByDescending() method in LINQ. I also added a property to the lists so I could group them by type. That got them in the right order on iOS, but then they were in the wrong order on Android. Apparently the OrderByDescending() method wasn’t doing anything on that version for some reason. I suspect that Android handles files in a special way, so how do I tell it not to?

Comment: if you are using the file system timestamps to order by, I'd suggest doing some simple testing to determine if this is actually behaving like you expect.  It doesn't sound like it is.  If this method isn't reliable on both platforms, then explicitly including the order in the file name might be a better approach.

Comment: @Jason I don't know how to do that or if I can do it because the reason that I was trying to sort by last write time was because the user is going to be able to edit these lists and add their own and I want the one that they edited the most recently to be at the top of its group (but the lists should start out in the order in the pictures).